# how do i retrieve hard disk information which is connected to server?Example C /C code?

Tags: c++, c, windows, disk

I am very new to Windows programming. so can you help me to get sample program(C/C++) which i can get all the hard disk information which is connected to my server.

I am using windows 2008 R2 sp1 server and also connected more than one hard disk to server.

Please help me to get this information.

Thanks,
Deepesh C.P

Comment: "all the hard disk information" is pretty vague, to put it mildly. The more specific you can be in your request, the better of answers you're likely to get. At first blush, "WMI" seems like the obvious route, but it's not clear whether it can provide the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI query to extract disk information.

```
SELECT Name,VolumeName from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType='3'
```

Search fro WMI API using with you can execute above command from C/C++ code.  [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10539/Making-WMI-Queries-In-C) is more details and sample code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made this query working but using this query i am getting only logical disk details. My actual requirement is to get information about all the hard disk connected in to my server.

Comment: @user1488334 : Use Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk class to get physical disk information. All data you will get into raw performance counters. visit to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394308(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.

Comment: Now i am to get this class but still not able to verify or get the total usage of disks or difference between total hard disk usaged and current usage from those parameters.I think i am not fully understand about that parameters.Please help me on this.

Comment: Not much sure... you may need to summat disk usage(or free usage) for all logical disk assoicated with physical device id.For ex. Select FreeSpace, Size from Win32_LogicalDisk where DeviceID =<deviceId>.

Answer (score 1):

Following API's must be useful

DisplayVolumePaths
GetDiskFreeSpace
CreateFile

Refer these links aswell

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/vcgeneral/thread/1d4fda3c-885f-46e2-bc32-80c4426510dc

Answer (score 0):

As a start I would read up on the Windows API.

To get all logical drives on a windows system use

```
DWORD WINAPI GetLogicalDrives(void);
```

or

```
DWORD WINAPI GetLogicalDriveStrings(
  __in   DWORD nBufferLength,
  __out  LPTSTR lpBuffer
);
```

As see on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364972(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am trying to get physical disk usage using power shell.But i am not able to understand how to get in this using Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk.Please help on this which will get some more idea about power shell also.